# In a Marionette View Am I Better Off Publishing an Event or Calling Another Objects Method

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, marionette

My Marionette module calls another objects method:

```
@App.module 'Views', (Views, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->
  class Views.MyView extends Marionette.ItemView
    template: "my-template"

    events:
      'click .btn': '_doSomething'

    _doSomething: ->
      params =
        action: 'myAction'

      App.Util.Actions.doSomething(params)
```

I am a bit bothered by the dependency that this module has on the App.Util.Actions object.

Am I better off triggering an event in order to loosen that dependency?

```
@App.module 'Views', (Views, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->
  class Views.MyView extends Marionette.ItemView
    template: "my-template"

    events:
      'click .btn': '_doSomething'

    _doSomething: ->
      params =
        action: 'myAction'

      App.vent.trigger 'DoSomething', params
```

I could then have another object subscribe to this event.

I know this might not be directly related to Marionette and might be an overall design question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, it is best to trigger an event rather than to directly call another object's method.

**Making your application more modular is always a good thing.** If you are concerned about the coupling of your view to `App.Util.Actions` at this point in development, then imagine how much more coupled it will become later on if no changed are made. It would best to go ahead and loosen the coupling before your application becomes too complex. Having the view trigger an event would allow the application to be more decoupled and will allow the application to be more maintainable, scalable, and organized in the future.